# Is it possible to have localised Windows user names?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, localization

Is it possible to have localised Windows user names?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "localised user names"? Just the names or do you mean a different Windows UI localization scheme for different accounts?

Comment: Why do you have the security tag? How is that relevant to the names?

Comment: Do you mean light weight active directory[http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3080681/Exploring-Windows-2003-Security-Additional-Active-Directory-Authentication-Improvements.htm]?

Comment: Do you mean names with Unicode characters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.  In fact I set up accounts with localized names (Irish Gaelic) just the other week.  Windows NT since version 3.1 has supported Unicode as it's native character set.

Comment: although you may have to install the MUI Pack on a server that you cannot administer remotely if the UI is in a language or charactor set you do not understand.

Comment: @Jim B - correct, good observation.